# Trying to move data from XML to an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: xml, excel, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to learn how to use PowerShell to speed up some tasks at work.

My goal is to take an XML document that lists some data about a product, and take the data from a certain recurring subnode and place it into a new row in Excel.

So the XML might look something like this (including the "sequence" attribute):

```
<xml>  
  <tracks> 
    <track sequence="1"> 
      <tracktitle>StuffIWant</tracktitle>
    </track>
    <track sequence="2">
      <tracktitle>StuffIWant2</tracktitle>
    </track>
    <track sequence="3">
      <tracktitle>StuffIWant3</tracktitle>
    </track>
  </tracks>
</xml>
```

And I want to take each `tracktitle` and place it in a row in excel.

I'm at the point where I can place one specific thing in Excel, like a single entity such as `xml.artist.artistname`, but if I want to loop the process to grab all the tracks then I don't know how to properly write the loop. I've tried a bunch of different things, but here's the thing that makes the most sense in my head (`$books` is the XML document I'm working with):

```
$row = 5
foreach ($track in $books.tracks) {
  $track = $books.tracks.track.tracktitle
  $excelworksheet.cells.item($row, 2) = $track
  $row++
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to access the `track`-property in the xml to actually get the array of track-elements. `tracks` is a single node, while it **contains** multiple `track`-elements (that you can access as an array).
- You're not using the current item `$track` inside your loop.
- `$books.tracks` isn't valid with the included sample. You're missing the `xml` root-element

Try this:

```
$row = 5
foreach ($track in $books.xml.tracks.track) {
    $title = $track.tracktitle
    $excelworksheet.cells.item($row, 2) = $title
    $row++
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the information! I have a question - the xml file that I'm working with doesn't actually have an `<xml>` element, is it still necessary? I just put it in the example xml setup and forgot to add it in my question.

Comment: Also - in your example, how does the system know that $track is pointing to the .track node? Could you have also written line 3 as `$blue = $blue.tracktitle`? Or does the name actually have to match the xml node?

Comment: If it isn't there in the real file then you don't need to access `xml`, but I had to use it since the xml-tree was built that way in your sample input

Comment: In the start of the loop, `$track` was the current `track`-item, but I replaced `$track`'s value with the tracktitle. Changed it now to `$title` to make it clear (sry, my answer was basically a copy paste of yours so I didn't notice it). :-) There's no relationship between the xml-file and a variable-name. Variables can be named whatever you want.

Comment: Ahh ok cool. Yeah a lot of the tutorials/examples I saw had variables matching whatever they wanted to address. Makes sense for neatness and readability of course, but to a noob like me I thought that was required and it was throwing me off. By the way, your answer worked exactly how I wanted it to! I can't thank you enough!